# Once I run the project, How to display a previously selected file in the text box

Tags: vb6

Using VB 6

Once I run the project, How to display a previously selected file in the text box.

Am using open dialog in my project, once am selecting the file from browse, then selected file is display in the text box. Then I executed the project and closed the project.

Next time I am opening the project, previously selected path and file will display in the text box.

I don’t want to select the file again from the browse, whenever I needed I will select from the browse, otherwise it will display a previously selected file.

How to display a previously selected file in the text box?

Need VB Code Help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you exit your program (like when the form closes) it should save a path to the previously selected file somewhere - in registry or in a configuration file. Then when the program starts it can read the saved values and put it into the text box.

Comment: @Sharptooth - How can i save, am new to vb, please.

Comment: You need to use functions for file manipulation or system registry manipulation.

Comment: The most obvious way in VB6 is to use SaveSetting/GetSetting calls.